# The Sturm-Liouville equations, the Schrodinger equation and the wave equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I heard in a [online quantum mechanics lecture](https://youtu.be/DNzu7oSDSnU?t=7m49s) that Schrödinger equation is an instance of the [Sturm-Liouville equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) and that is the super position of its stationary states gives the most general solution. I have two questions:

1. How can the Schrödinger equation be a Sturm-Liouville equation the former is a partial differential equation and the latter is an ordinary differential equation?
2. I am sure that [the standard wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) does not have the property stated above. That is, we can not form any solution to the wave equation by the superposition of its stationary states. But can I generalise this to the following?

> The stationary states of a differential equation can be superimposed to form any solution if and only if it is a Sturm-Liouville equation.

I know that some of what I have asked may make no sense, if so please can you explain why this is the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **time-independent** Schrödinger equation in **one** dimension is given by,

$$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2 \psi(x)}{dx^2} = \left[E-V(x)\right]\psi(x)$$

which is clearly in a Sturm-Liouville form, $y'' \sim Q(x)y.$ In the case of the time-dependent equation, we have that,

$$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2 \psi(x,t)}{\partial x^2} + V(x)\psi(x,t) = i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi(x,t)}{\partial t}.$$

By employing separation of variables, $\psi(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, and dividing by $\psi$ on both sides, we can reduce the problem to two ordinary differential equations, and the Sturm-Liouville form arises for the spatially dependent part, $X(x)$. The $E$ is the separation of variables constant.

---

For a thorough treatment of the Sturm-Liouville equation as a Schrödinger equation and the WKB method, see *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers* by Carl M. Bender, et al.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, do you possibly the answer to my second question?